# Rails - how to create file (XML) and save it into Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, amazon-s3, paperclip

I need to generate all my products from database table into the XML file. Because my app run on Heroku, I need to use Amazon S3 as the storage.

Here's an example of on how to save an image:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
       :styles => {
       :thumb=> "100x100#",
       :small  => "400x400>" },
     :storage => :s3,
     :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
     :path => "/:style/:id/:filename"
```

Which makes me a bit confused... because I am not sure about the logic of this task.
My idea is to run an action (say `create_xml_feed`) in the `Products` controller

```
 xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new( :indent => 2 )
 xml.instruct! :xml, :encoding => "ASCII"
 xml.product do |p|
   p.name "Test"
 end
```

But here comes the problem - I don't know, how to save the newly created file into Amazon S3 Bucket.

I'd be grateful for each advance, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, create an active record class to hold your uploaded XML file. After this you can write the logic to create your xml string, create a new file by first creating a new instance of the XmlUploader class, then create the xml string you want, save it in a file and then assign this file as the attachment file. Once you save your xml file will be uploaded to s3.

```
class XmlUploader < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :uploaded_file, :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
  :path => "/:id/:filename"

  def create_uploaded_file
    xml = ::Builder::XmlMarkup.new( :indent => 2 )
    xml.instruct! :xml, :encoding => "ASCII"
    xml.product do |p|
      p.name "Test"
    end
    file_to_upload = File.open("some-file-name", "w")     
    file_to_upload.write(xml)
    file_to_upload.close()
    self.uploaded_file = File.open("some-file-name")
    self.save!
  end
end

class CreateXmlUploaders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :xml_uploaders do |t|
      t.attachment :uploaded_file
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

xml_file = XmlUploader.new
xml_file.create_uploaded_file
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Nakort. I've tried to implement it, but I got the errors while saving the file - `undefined method `uploaded_file=' for #<Class:0x0000012a22f710>`. I run the code like `XmlUploader.create_uploaded_file()`. Could you give me, please, a tip  on how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: You need to create an instance of the XmlUploader class, I will update the answer.
`

Comment: I am sorry for another question - this `xml_file = XmlUploader.new xml_file.create_uploaded file` should be in controller's action? When I put it there and run the code, I get `undefined local variable or method file' for #<ProductsController:0x0000010450b0e0>`. Sorry, I am just a bit confused... thank you.

Comment: Hey sorry I edited my comment there was a typo, I have updated the answer with the correct approach, basically just this: `xml_file = XmlUploader.new;xml_file.create_uploaded_file`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Nakort, the upload is working. Just one thing yet - to Amazon is always uploaded just an empty file. When I try `put xml`, I see the structure, but don't understand, why the content is not saved into the file.

Comment: You are right, as of now the file does not get written, you need to close the file after you write to it, then open it again to upload it. I have updated the example code to reflect this.